# TextView is not visible in Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, xml, textview, visibility, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/exerciseNameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:clickable="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exerciseNameButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:background="@drawable/button_no_bottom_border"
        android:text="@string/exercise_name"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/selected"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Label1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="10 X 10"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/unselected"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The textview is not displayed in the Android 5.1.1 but it is visible in android versions <5.0

I have no idea how to solve this.
I have also found that I couldn't see it in the preview even. Though I can select it from the preview but text 10X10  is not appearing.

Comment: you tried to change the textColor ?

Comment: Yes, I did change the text color but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Connect ADB to your test device and run [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) to see what is in the UI. It is possible that text color you are using had changed in Android 5.1.1.